# Format multiple files from command line or vim

Tags: shell, vim

Is there a command line utility to format multiple files from different programming languages ?

I was thinking something like:

```
format --indentation=spaces --size=2 --trim-whitespaces ./*.{php,js,cpp,sh}
```

If a command like this does not exist, how to do that in Vim? To format a single file in normal mode it is `gg=G`. But what about multiple files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vim in batch mode:

```bsh
vim -c "normal gg=G" -c "x"  x.py
```

This will invoke `gg=G` command in normal mode then `x` (save and exit) command. For multiple files you can create simple loop with globs:

```bsh
for i in ./*.{php,js,cpp,sh}; do
    vim -c "normal gg=G" -c "x" $i
done
```

Comment: For some weird reason this does not work inside loops. Doing `vim -c "normal gg=G" -c "x" $filename` works but if I do it inside a for loop or while loop vim will stop after the first files is formatted. From within loops Vim also alerts `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`